# I'm needing to produce a set of missing records in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a source table and a branch table.

I need to update the sequence by 1 starting with the max value and populate a branch number not already being used. My results should be Seqno starting at 1409 with a new branch number not in the source table already.

Here's what I have so far. I get all values 1409, but they need to be 1410, 1411,... and so on

```
SELECT  S.SOURCEID
    ,  MAX(S.SEQNO) + 1 AS NEWSEQ
    , B.BRANCH_NO 
     FROM SOURCE S, BRANCH B
   WHERE S.SOURCEID = '607'
   AND B.BRANCH <> S.BRANCH
    GROUP BY S.SOURCEID,B.BRANCH,S.SEQNO
```

[image: Source]
[image]

Comment: When posting code or data please use text to post them with - do not use images as this makes it impossible to copy the code or data into a workspace and make use of it to develop an answer for your question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use ROWNUM instead of `1`.

```
SELECT S.SOURCEID
      ,(SELECT MAX(SEQNO) FROM SOURCE) + ROWNUM AS NEWSEQ
      ,B.BRANCH_NO 
  FROM SOURCE S
  JOIN BRANCH B ON B.BRANCH <> SB.BRANCH
 WHERE S.SOURCEID = '607'
 GROUP BY S.SOURCEID,B.BRANCH
```

Using only the MAX condition will give the max from the query not from the whole table. So I have used a sub-query for that. Also, I have changed your join to modern syntax.

P.S. - Not sure why you have used `<>` condition instead of the equality condition. Normally we use equality condition for joins.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. This is not starting the seqno of the resultset at 1409.  It starts it at 1691

Comment: ok i added the where statement inside the nest.     (SELECT MAX(SEQNO) FROM MARKET_SOURCE_BRANCH SB where sb.mktsrc_id = '607') + ROWNUM AS NEWSEQ

Comment: @GET_Amazed, Is it working now?

Comment: This field is. But now I need to use Branch numbers from the branch table that are not already in the source table for this 607 id

Comment: Please post another question for a new request.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `MAX(seqno) + 1` to generate the values (you will end up with duplicates if you run the query on a parallel system). Instead, create a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE source__seqno START WITH 1409;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO source (sourceid, seqno, branch)
SELECT S.SOURCEID
     , source__seqno.NEXTVAL
     , B.BRANCH
FROM   SOURCE S
       INNER JOIN BRANCH B
       ON (B.BRANCH <> S.BRANCH)
WHERE  S.SOURCEID = '607'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08cd730589cd43d2ae4ef604f0aff02a)*

Comment: I have no privilege' to create sequence

Comment: @GET_Amazed Then ask the DBA to create it for you.